# Extra spacing between number and *

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm trying to build a table containing numbers and ** for passing up to a certain significance level.
For some reason, for one column it adds extra space between the number and ** and I'm not understanding why, any idea?
Btw, I'm using siunitx to center by decimal point.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{c c S S c}
                
                \hline
                \textbf{Index} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{ADF} & \textbf{KPSS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Results}} \\
                
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{S\&P500}} & Prices & -0,52 & 6,59** & Non-stationary \\
                & Returns & -65,90** & 0,10 & Stationary \\
                
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{DAX}} & Prices  & -2,35 & 5,37** & Non-stationary \\
                & Returns & -62,77** & 0,05   & Stationary \\
                
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{FTSE}} & Prices & -2,72 & 4,04** & Non-stationary \\
                & Returns & -39,09** & 0,05 & Stationary \\
                
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{HSI}} & Prices & -3,88 & 0,98** & Non-stationary \\
                & Returns & -43,23** & 0,05 & Stationary \\
                
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            %\begin{tablenotes}
            %\item \noindent Notes:
            %\item - The 5\% and 1\% critical value for the ADF test are $-3.41$ and $-3.96$, respectively.
            %\item - The 5\% and 1\% critical value for the KPSS test are 0.15 and 0.22, respectively.
            %\item - * and ** denote the rejection of the null hypothesis at 5\% and 1\% significance levels, %respectively.
            %\end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \caption{\label{tab:3}Output of the ADF and KPSS tests, for the returns and prices of the four indices in study}
    \end{table}
\end{center}
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you have `S`'s in the align option of `tabular` environment?

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela That's a tabular column type provided by `siunitx` package.

Comment: Please provide a [complete example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time.

Comment: Off topic: it's counter-productive, in fact an error, to wrap a `center` environment around `table` which is a float.  Instead, put `\centering` inside the float.

Comment: It's very peculiar that both columns containing `**` have the `S` format.  The only difference that I can see is that the values in the column with the extra space are all negative.  Yes, we do need a compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a ‘model’ which defines the space to reserve for a number in column type `S[table-format=...]`. This column type can be used in not only the default `tabular`, but also many derived tabular environments, including the `threeparttable` in OP's example.

In the example below, a tabular preamle `c c S[table-format=-2.2{**}] S[table-format=2.2{**}] c` is used. Depending on which document class and style setting are in use, the output may vary, but the tabular preamble is reusable.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{c c S[table-format=-2.2{**}] S[table-format=2.2{**}] c}
            
            \hline
            \textbf{Index} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{ADF} & \textbf{KPSS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Results}} \\
            
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{S\&P500}} & Prices & -0,52 & 6,59** & Non-stationary \\
            & Returns & -65,90** & 0,10 & Stationary \\
            
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{DAX}} & Prices  & -2,35 & 5,37** & Non-stationary \\
            & Returns & -62,77** & 0,05   & Stationary \\
            
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{FTSE}} & Prices & -2,72 & 4,04** & Non-stationary \\
            & Returns & -39,09** & 0,05 & Stationary \\
            
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{HSI}} & Prices & -3,88 & 0,98** & Non-stationary \\
            & Returns & -43,23** & 0,05 & Stationary \\
            
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        %\begin{tablenotes}
        %\item \noindent Notes:
        %\item - The 5\% and 1\% critical value for the ADF test are $-3.41$ and $-3.96$, respectively.
        %\item - The 5\% and 1\% critical value for the KPSS test are 0.15 and 0.22, respectively.
        %\item - * and ** denote the rejection of the null hypothesis at 5\% and 1\% significance levels, %respectively.
        %\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \caption{\label{tab:3}Output of the ADF and KPSS tests, for the returns and prices of the four indices in study}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: +1. I think you might as well rid of the `threeparttable` stuff as it's not at all needed. (By keeping the `threeparttable` stuff around, you may inadvertently be creating the impression that it's doing some useful here.)

Comment: @Mico Seeing there is a commented out `tablenotes` block in OP's example, perhaps `threeparttable` is required in the unsimplified document. I've added some explanation in response to your concern.